# Is integral operator hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra

If v is an element of a vector space of complex functions and A is an operator such that
Av=$\int_{0}^{x}vdx$,
then is A hermitian?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is probably a good idea to tell us what is the complex vector space you work with and with which Hermitian product it is endowed. I can probably make a guess but your question have to be clear and not open to interpretation. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: This is actually a question in quantum mechanics, where the vector space is the set of all complex valued functions. I ended up with a double integral .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the operator $A$ on $L^2([0,a])$ by

$$ Av(x) = \int_{0}^{x} v(t) \, dt. $$

We can easily check that $A$ is a bounded operator on $L^2([0,a])$. Then for any $u, v \in L^2([0,a])$, the computation

$$
(u, Av)_{L^2}
= \int_{0}^{a} u(x) \overline{Av(x)} \, dx
= \int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{x}  u(x) \overline{v(t)} \,dt dx
= \int_{0}^{a}\int_{t}^{a}  u(x) \overline{v(t)} \,dx dt
$$

shows that the adjoint $A^*$ of $A$ satisfies

$$ A^* u(x) = \int_{x}^{a} u(t) \, dt. \tag{*} $$

Therefore $A \neq A^*$. (If you are worried about interchanging the order of integration, notice that the computation is justified when $u$ and $v$ are bounded in view of Fubini's theorem, and then $\text{(*)}$ extends to all of $L^2([0,a])$ by density argument.)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. Consider e.g. $u$ and $v$ the indicator functions of intervals $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ respectively, where $0 < a < b < c < d$.  Then $\langle u,\; A v\rangle   = 0$ but $\langle A u,\; v \rangle \ne 0$.